# How to match "prefix" and not whole string in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed documents, each with a field: "CodeName" that has values like the following:

```
document 1 has CodeName: "AAA01"
document 2 has CodeName: "AAA02"
document 3 has CodeName: "AAA03"
document 4 has CodeName: "BBB02"
```

When I try to use a match query on field:

```
query: {
"match": {
"CodeName": "AAA"
}
}
```

I expect to get results for "AAA01" and "AAA02", but instead, I am getting an empty array. When I pass in "AAA01" (I type in the whole thing), I get a result. How do I make it such that it matches more generically? I tried using "prefix" instead of "match" and am getting the same problem.

The mapping for "CodeName" is a "type": "string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expect to get results for "AAA01" and "AAA02"

This is not what Elastic Search expects. ES breaks your string into tokens using a tokenizer that you specify. If you didn't specify any tokenizer/analyzer, the default standard tokenizer splits words on spaces and hyphens etc. In your case, the tokens are stored as "AAA01", "AAA02" and so on. There is no such term as "AAA", and hence you don't get any results back.

To fix this, you can use match_phrase_prefix query or set the type of match query to be phrase_prefix . Try this code:

```
"query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
           "CodeName": "AAA"
        }
    }
```

OR

```
"query": {
        "match": {
           "CodeName": {
               "query": "AAA",
               "type": "phrase_prefix"
           }
        }
    }
```

Here is the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html. Also pay attention to the max_expansions parameter, as this query can be slow sometimes depending upon your data.

Note that for this technique, you should go with default mapping. You don't not to use nGram.

Comment: Thank you! When would you want to use nGram over this?

Comment: nGram takes more time at index creation and requires more storage, but at the same time provides faster search because all the tokens are pre-calculated. If the dataset is huge and you need multiple combination of tokens such as "AA", "AAA", "AAA0", "AAA01", using nGram makes more sense. For simpler requirements like yours and with limited dataset, phrase_prefix is usually sufficient and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know first of all you sould index your data using a tokenizer of type `nGram`.

You can check detailes [in documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)

COMMENT RELATED:
I'm familiar with symfony-way of using elasticsearch and we are using it like this:

```
indexes:
    search:
        client: default
        settings:
            index:
                analysis:
                    custom_index_analyzer:
                    type: custom
                    tokenizer: nGram
                    filter: [lowercase, kstem]
                tokenizer:
                    nGram:
                        type: nGram
                        min_gram: 2
                        max_gram: 20
    types:
        skill:
            mappings:
                skill.name:
                     search_analyzer: custom_index_analyzer
                     index_analyzer: custom_index_analyzer
                     type: string
                     boost: 1
```

Comment: How do I set this? Do I have to explicitly declare this for the "CodeName" field? If so, how?

Comment: In the process of indexing documents (3 indexed so far), it appears to still not be working... not sure if this is because analyzers kick in after all documents are finished indexing or something.. at this time, not even "AAA01" is able to match.

Comment: If you are working on your local machine you can open `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v` in your browser to see all your indexes and `http://127.0.0.1:9200/<index>/_search/?type=<type>&pretty=true` to check certain type details